# Is there a way to insert javascript code to track and record clicks, requests and responses?

Tags: javascript, request, response, tracking, recording

I have a website, with links,external and internal iframes, javascript calls, etc. not a simple site.
For supporting problems with the site, I am searching for a way to insert some "wrapping" javascript or any other code, so when "turned on" it will record the activity on the site for the specific user: record the button clicks, requests and responses, and even html shown on screen.

Then the user , when facing an issue, can just turn on the "tracking", make the actions to reach the error, and send the traces - while having requests, responses, html shown, click to reproduce it would be easy to understand issue fast and solve it.

Anything that i can do about it? ofcourse, without changing the already existing code and links.

thanks,
Tal

Comment: You mean like google analytics? or something else

Comment: I need such functionality for support. as far as i know analytics are just for analysis of website clicks. For support - i need that for enabling via a toggle/flag on the server side/client side to record anythign that happens. clicks as well, but most important are the entire requests and responses. Another option is to record video  of the flow user does - is that possible ? (without external tools)

Comment: Anyone ? I guess no ways or any library that can support that?